# How to implement Camera Based app in android using google camera(GCAM)?

Tags: android, github, android-camera2, camera-api

I want to to develop a android app using GCAM(Google camera) to capture the images.Is GCAM is open source available?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Since we have requirement to develop a app using GCAM.So i have posted this question here

Comment: @MorrisonChang I suppose you don't know what GCam is, so you write here these not interesting comments...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, google has not published code of "GCAM" application, neither jetpack's CameraX. The public is only Camera 2 API. You can also look here - example of use Camera 2 API, from googleexaples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic